# Can't set headers after they are sent when i try make a post using my controllers

Tags: javascript, node.js, controller, routes

i'm having a problem here.

I have this piece of code:

```
var controller = require('./controllers/controller');

  app.post('/',
    controller.create,
  );
```

And inside that i have:

```
exports.create = function(req, res, next) {
   res.send('test');
};
```

Yes, i'm using a form to make a post.

The code is not working, the console will show: Can't set headers after they sent.

But if i change the code to:

```
var controller = require('./controllers/controller');

  app.post('/', function(req, res {
    res.send('test');
  });
```

Will work!!!!! Why is that???

UPDATE:

I don't know if maybe this is causing that, but i have this following code:

```
var home = require('./controllers/home');

  app.get('/',
    home.index
  );
```

And inside that i have this code:

```
exports.index = function(req, res, next) {

var url         = "someurl/"
var stringify   = "";

var request = https.get(url, function(response) {

    response.on('data', function(json) {
        stringify += json
    });

    response.on('end', function() {
        var json = JSON.parse(stringify);
        var data = json.feed.entry;

        res.render('index', {
              data: data
        });
    });

 });
};
```

if i pass the code of the first controller to the home controller, will work.. but i need separate.

Comment: Try `return res.send('test')`

Comment: same result @VsevolodGoloviznin

Comment: Just a second, i will update my post.

Comment: if i pass the code of the first controller to the home controller, will work.. but i need separate

Comment: Have you tried not passing the `next` parameter to your function?

Comment: Can you try this `app.post('/',controller.create);` without the last comma

Comment: sorry.. this was a type error in the post.. i'm not using the comma in the code, if i use the app will not run..

Comment: if i use the code in the route, without call controller.create, will work.. this is not making sense..

Answer (score 0):

```
response.on('end', function() {
    var json = JSON.parse(stringify);
    var data = json.feed.entry;

    res.render('index', {
          data: data
    });
});
```

Here you're trying to listen for when the response ends. This event only fires when the response has been sent to the client already, including the response headers. Your call to `res.render` fails because the response has ended. You can't then continue to send more data to the client. Anything that happens in the "end" event handler cannot write to the response stream anymore.